# Incrementing a sequence in SQL Server 2012 when new row is inserted to a table

Tags: sql-server, max, sequence

- I have a table `organisation` with the column `customer_number`
- I have a sequence `organisation_customernumber_seq`

The sequence starts from highest value +1 in the `customer_number` column. I create it as follows in JBOSS WildFly's FlyWay in an sql-script:

```
DECLARE @max int;
SELECT @max = MAX(customer_number)+1
FROM organisation

exec('CREATE SEQUENCE organisation_customernumber_seq
    START WITH ' + @max +
'   INCREMENT BY 1;')
```

That works as intended.

Now, how to make it so, that each time `organisation` table gets a new row inserted into it, the sequence would get the highest value of column `customer_number` again as it did in the creation of the sequence?

Comment: I've got the feeling, that you are trying to cut bread with a chain saw... Please provide some more details about your goal! And you might read about the [XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: You need to amend the query that adds rows to the table, so that it uses the [`NEXT VALUE FOR`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878370.aspx) construct to obtain its values.

Comment: Are you sure sql has a sequence? or maybe you are trying to make it complicated with postgresql